# Out of memory exception

Tags: c#, list, exception, out-of-memory

I have a list of a class type which contains (string, string, string, string, int, DateTime, DateTime)
The total amount of chars in the strings combined equals 28.

I read in a file to populate the list which will finish with 19,000,000 (nineteen-million) of these objects in the list.

I read in the file and add to the list like so

```
public void ReadDocGrabValues(string fileREAD)
{
    using (var file = new StreamReader(fileREAD))
    {
        var j = file.ReadLine();

        while (j != null)
        {
            mylist.Add(new IDandAGE(j.Substring(0, 15), j.Substring(16, 1), j.Substring(18, 6), j.Substring(25, 6), 0, DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today));
            j = file.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Which shouldn't be the problem. I then go through the entire list to work out the DateTime objects from the two strings.

```
public void ConvertYOBDOI()
{
    foreach (IDandAGE x in mylist)
    {
        string IssueDate = (x.StringDOD.Substring(0,4) + "-" + x.StringDOD.Substring(4,2) + "-01");
        string BirthDate = (x.StringYOB.Substring(0,4) + "-" + x.StringYOB.Substring(4,2) + "-01");
        x.DeathDate= DateTime.Parse(DeathDate);
        x.YearOfBirth = DateTime.Parse(BirthDate);

     }
}
```

I then go through the entire list again to work out the age value.

```
public void DateCalc()
{
    foreach (IDandAGE w in mylist)
    {
        w.Age = w.DateOfDeath.Year - w.YearOfBirth.Year;
        if (w.YearOfBirth > w.DateOfDeath.AddYears(-w.Age)) w.Age--;

    }
}
```

And finally I write out the values I want from the list to a file.

```
public void CreateAgeFile()
{
   StreamWriter a = new StreamWriter(@"C:\GetAgeTest.txt");

    foreach (IDandAGE x in mylist)
    {
       String f = (x.ID + "," + x.Gender + "," + x.StringYOB + "," + x.StringDOD + "," + x.Age + ",NULL,NULL,NULL");
        a.WriteLine(f);
    }
    a.Close();

}
```

I've really only just started coding so apologies in advance for it being inefficient/rubbish/not being able to answer my own question.

I guess it's possible that it's giving me this exception for multiple reasons since I traverse through the list several times.

Any help or suggestions welcomed.

Thank you.

Comment: Where exactly do you get the error?

Comment: Is there any reason you need 19M records in-memory at the same time (`mylist.Add()`)? Try streaming it to a file directly.

Comment: These operations can't be done once instead of iterating each time this list

Comment: That is too much for memory :)

Comment: What, and where is `mylist`?

Comment: Sorry I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Is it possible to do my other functions without the list being complete?

Comment: It seems that you can execute all this operations directly in the first loop without involving any list.

Comment: I didn't show you all the code because it's not necessary. My program works fine with smaller list sizes. public List<IDandAGE> mylist = new List<IDandAGE>(); is in the class

Comment: Do you mind showing me Steve?

Comment: @Mitchell re "without the list being complete" - yes, "iterator  blocks" (aka `yield return`) are ideal for that; here, there *is no list* - just a state machine

Comment: As pseudocode, before the first loop, open also the StreamWriter, after reading a line build the class instance, then execute on it the code of your `ConvertYOBDOI` and `DateCalc`. Now you are ready to write on the StreamWriter. Also the answer from @MarcGravell is really good to start this approach

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are accessing 19M records, then yes: you need to at least think about memory. You are currently storing them all in a list, so they won't be collectable. If you are on 32-bit (or 64-bit-enabled with prefer-32-bit checked) then this will be tight. A better idea is probably to use an iterator block so that you don't need them all in memory at once:

```
public IEnumerable<IDandAGE> ReadDocGrabValues(string fileREAD)
{
    foreach(string j in File.ReadLines(fileREAD))
    {
        yield return new IDandAGE(j.Substring(0, 15), j.Substring(16, 1),
            j.Substring(18, 6), j.Substring(25, 6), 0,
            DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today);
    }
}
...
foreach (IDandAGE w in ReadDocGrabValues(path))
{
    // do per-item processing
}
```